# Lodash tree shaking with this syntax import _get from 'lodash/get';

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

i am trying to refactor app. Here everywhere was

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

I am trying to reduce bundle size. My question is

Is this syntax will work for tree shaking ?

```
import _get from 'lodash/get';
```

And one more question, do i need to add something to webpack? I checked this page https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ and didnt find answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Your kind of bypassing tree-shaking here, so doing what your doing should reduce your bundle size without it.  The tree shaking is more for `import {get} from 'lodash'`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/tree-shaking/


// This still pulls in all of lodash even if everything is configured right.
import { sortBy } from "lodash";

Comment: Yes, I haven't used `lodash` for a while, but from what I can remember if you include only `lodash`, it will setup all the functions for chaining, as such all functions get bound.  So one thing to remember when doing `lodash/get` you loose this chaining feature, but gain a smaller bundle.  In a nutshell, I don't believe `lodash` is a good example lib for demonstrating Tree Shaking..

Comment: So i need use lodash-es ?

Comment: That's a tricky question, one of my biggest gripes about `lodash` is how it got fragmented into other packages.  And `lodash-es` has now muddied the water even more :(.  The reason why this is a big issue with me is that you now have three ways to execute 1 function.. `lodash/get` `lodash.get`, `lodash-es/get`..

Comment: Now why is this a problem you ask,.  Well if you have total control of your project and are not using any 3rd party lib, then `lodash-es` would seem a good idea,. But if you use any third part libs, then they might uses `lodash.get`, and another uses `lodash/get`, and you use `lodash-es/get`.  Bundle explosion. :(  Basically 3 copies of the same function.   Personally I would say the rule should be, if you plan on publishing, use `lodash/get`..

Comment: yes... understood, yes, i installed lodash-es. But because i have other packages of APP as an npm modules and they have simple lodash. I dont see any result after i changed lodash to lodash-es in one repo... :|

Comment: Yes, it's a common issue with `lodash`.  But what you could try is -> https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash  This will hopefully transform your 3rd party libs into the more bundle friendly `lodash/get`,.  After that you will hopefully see some sort of reduction..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) module instead of the normal `lodash` module. Then, you can use the functions / imports just like this (normal ES6 module imports):

```
import { get } from 'lodash-es';
```

Comment: If you read the comments, that's fine.  But unfortunately the OP uses third party libs, that in turn use lodash.  So all that just gets blown out the water.. :(